# Flutter Notification shows as shadow/gray

Tags: firebase, flutter, notifications

I'm using Firebase as my notification handler and the notification image works well with IOS. For some reason, in some android devices the notification image appears to show the shape of the logo but just gray.

So far this is what I've tried:

1. Used mipmap and drawable as my meta-data resource in the AndroidManifest.xml
2. Created /android/app/src/main/res/raw/keep.xml

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:keep="@drawable/*" />`
3. Ensured that the notification image is transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon to be used for notifications must be white-colored and with transparent background else it will show a grey-colored box.

for more help check this article https://medium.com/nonstopio/change-the-firebase-notification-icon-in-a-flutter-245b7f7dc546